# Difference between Shannon Entropy limit and Kolmogorov Complexity?

Tags: algorithms, computer-science, computability, entropy, compression

I've read in numerous places that Shannon Entropy provides some kind of fundamental limit to the compressibility of messages (according to, for example, Shannon's source coding theorem). I have also read about Kolmogorov complexity, which establishes a different kind of limit to compression by considering the shortest program that could output a given piece of text.

My question is: **How are these related? They can't both be limit of compression.**

There have been previous questions on MSE which superficially resemble what I'm asking but have never been given an appropriate answer. I'm looking for:

- A clear explanation of the different notions (if they exist) of compression potentially being discussed.
- A clear explanation of what the different compression-limits are and why they differ. This should also mention something about why K. complexity is uncomputable whereas Shannon entropy is computable (I understand the proof of the uncomputability of K-complexity, I'm just saying it should be clear why there's a difference).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shannon Entropy is about compression of (long) words generated by biased die toss. And if dice entropy is $H$, we can't (on average) compress results of $n$ tosses to less than $n\cdot H$ bits.

Kolmogorov Complexity is about compression of arbitrary words. Of course, if word is generated by the same die, it's average complexity will be $n\cdot H + O(1)$.

However, if your data is not generated by biased die, then you may be able to achieve better compression than just recoding individual chars. For example, if you want to send $n$ first digits of $\pi$, it's quite easy to compress them to $\log(n) + O(1)$ bits: if we know that we want to send first digits of $\pi$, it's enough to send number of digits we want to send (which will require $\log(n)$ bits), and then we will be able to calculate necessary digits by ourselves.

About computability - I think good intuition will be that to compress something, we need to find some "patterns" (ways to distinguish our sequence from arbitrary random in the same alphabet) in object we want to compress. If we use, for example, arithmetic coding - we only use very simple pattern of noticing that different symbols have different probabilities. If we want to compress word for Kolmogorov's decompessor, we are interested in any computable "patterns", which is much larger and more complex set. And discovering arbitrary computable "pattern" turns out to be uncomputable.

Comment: Firstly thank you very much!

I have 2 questions:

1. You mention early in your answer that K complexity and Entropy agree (give or take a model of computation) on compression for biased-die-toss-data. How did you do this and can you be sure these are the only kinds of inputs for which they agree?

2. Are you saying that Shannon Entropy effectively measures the possible feasibility of a first-order probabilistic approximation to a text? If so, why is it relevant to information transfer? Why does it and not something like K complexity supposedly limit compression?

Comment: 1. Entropy applies only to biased die. If our data is generated by some other process we can't speak about probability of particular symbols, and so we can't speak about entropy. Kolmogorov and Entropy encoders agrees because entropy can't outperform Kolmogorov encoder by more than a constant (nothing computable can), and Kolmogorov encoder can't outperform entropy encoder on die-toss-data (absolutely nothing can).

Comment: 2. It's the best compression we can achieve for arbitrary die-generated stream. And die-generated is probably the most complicated scenario for which it's possible to give exact bounds. K complexity can have better theoretical justifications, but due to uncomputability it's almost useless for practice purposes, while entropy compressors can be used in (and are widely used).

Comment: Final question (I promise!):

If you say entropy only applies to biased dice-rolls, why is it used for general communication? It was created for engineers in networking and surely they don't genuinely believe the outputs of their departments are just the product of random processes?

Comment: It's not dice rolling, but we still can model this process as such (assume that characters are independent). This will mean that we will not be able to distinguish text from random character-wise permutation, but this approach is still useful - for example, if we transfer English text, "probability" of encountering different bytes varies a lot, and this can be exploited for compression.